# Java 1.7 update 07 and Google Chrome

Tags: java, google-chrome

I've just updated Java from 1.6 to 1.7 via the Software Centre - removing the old Java 1.6 and selecting the new Java 1.7.

Firefox works fine.

But when I use Google Chrome to access a Java test website it says the Plugin is out of date. I click on run anyway and it says that it's running version 1.7.

I've cleared Chrome's Cache and Plugin data and this hasn't changed anything.

Anyway ideas?

(Ps. It's Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit)

Comment: Which version of chrome are you using?

Comment: Chrome Version 21.0.1180.89

Comment: I've found that loads of other ubuntu users are having problems with the same thing since Java was updated to version 1.7 update 7 - and some have reported it as a bug. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: I've now removed the Open Java and replaced it with the Oracle Java and I still get the same problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved - I don't know how - but I'm guessing it was due to an update in Google Chrome as it no longer says the plugin is out of date.